# Running Sum for the last 12 months

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I want to write a query that returns the sum of last 12 months of records for total employees. I tried this query below but it returns incorrect values. [image: The image below is the table I am trying to run the query on. Year Period is ranked based on end_date]. For 2021P11 I want the output to show the sum of all employees that are in term_employees column going back to 2020P12 which is 12 periods prior.

Is there a way to get this?

```
from output_staging as os1
inner join output_staging as os2
    on os1.end_date > os2.start_date_11_periods_prior
    and os1.entity_id = os2.entity_id
    and os1.employee_position = os2.employee_position
group by 1,2,3
order by 1 desc;
```

Comment: If you are going to include the `entity_id` in your group by, than that's as granular as the data in your output is going to be and it will be summed at that low level of granularity. You can either take that out of your `GORUP BY` so that the `Sum(term_employees)` will roll up to the `year_period` or you can remove your `GROUP BY` entirely and use a window function like `SUM(term_employees) OVER (PARTITION BY year_period)` to your `SELECT`. It's tough to say which will work better for your needs though.

Comment: @JNevill I will need to include entity_id in the granularity as that is a requirement as well